# How to create gridview using repeater controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, repeater

How can I design the below type of grid view?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Since am new to ASP.NET, please provide some guidelines to create the page.

Comment: use data list or repeater instead of gridview.

Comment: hire a developer from freelancing site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a repeater. Within that repeater you can create a `<table>` to display the details. Then just databind the repeater.